# Is using 2d ImageView fast enough?

Tags: android, android-imageview

After using AndEngine, e3roid for testing: I need to develop an application with a view where I can get about **60fps** while **printing about 40 sprites** with transparency, and changing background color **while playing music in background**.

Because I need to have full control on screen rotations, and I don't see the point to use a BIG game engine (with physic engine, map loader...) for just this I was asking myself if I use a `SurfaceView` like told there:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html

then in the "moon lander" SDK example will I be able to get a fluid program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is yes!